# Alternative to wordpress.com for free WordPress hosting?

Tags: wordpress, hosting, web-hosting

Didn't find a similar question here on SO. There's an [old, closed question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15755/hosting-alternatives-to-wordpress-com?newreg=a13a1a4a200a453d8740322bc0299556) (2011) on WordPress SE, where page.ly (not free, premium service, hundreds of dollars a month) and [WPEngine](https://wpengine.com/) (also not free, plans start from $25/mo) are mentioned. Any other, free alternatives?

Comment: You didn't find any similar question because it's not the place for it. This tag is for programming-specific questions about the WordPress content management system. Off-topic questions include those about theme development, WordPress administration, management best practices, server configuration, etc. These are best asked on the dedicated WordPress Development Stack Exchange site (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com).

Comment: The old, closed question was marked off-topic too. Tough luck, I guess stackexchange is not a place to ask for this kind of question.

Comment: Nothing is ever free, you can get really cheap hosting for around 40$ a year (at least in europe).

Comment: I do manage my self-hosted WP installations on paid hosts, just wondering about the available free offerings here. So far wordpress.com has been my go-to, but I recently: 1) wanted to install a plugin not installed by default there; 2) I find it quite strict regarding duplicate content and flagging them as spam/SEO-gaming, even though in my case it is not.

Answer (score -1):

I use Google Cloud to host WordPress, and their [Always Free Tier](https://cloud.google.com/free) Compute Engine Instance is enough for a small personal site.

It is a little bit more complicated to setup than WPEngine, but the easiest way to host WordPress on Google Cloud is to use a prebuilt image from the [Google Cloud Marketplace](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/browse?q=wordpress). I use images created by Bitnami, such as this one: https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/bitnami-launchpad/wordpress

On the [Configuration page](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/config/bitnami-launchpad/wordpress), you will need to adjust the machine size to be "Micro" and make sure the Region is one of the regions mentioned on the Free Tier page.

[image: Setting to qualify for free tier]

The estimated cost will say something like $5.13, but if you have everything configured in a way that matches up with the Compute Engine section of the Free Tier page, it will show up on your bill at $0. Of course there are other things Google Cloud may charge you for, such as if you go over the 1GB data transfer limit, but even so your hosting could be pretty inexpensive if your site is not too busy.